# Matching on compound _id fields in MongoDB aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm a MongoDB novice so please forgive me if this question has an obvious answer...

**Context:**

I've followed the [example in the MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/hierarchical-aggregation/) to implement hierarchical aggregation using map-reduce. The example uses a "compound" `_id` field as a map-reduce key producing aggregate documents like this...

```
{
   _id: { u: "rick", d: ISODate("2010-10-10T14:00:00Z") },
   value: {
       ts: ISODate('2010-10-10T15:01:00Z'),
       total: 254,
       count: 10,
       mean: 25.4 }
}
```

This is all well and good. My particular use case requires that values for *several* similar keys be emitted each `map` step. For example...

```
{
   _id: { u: "rick", d: ISODate("2010-10-10T14:00:00Z"), hobby: "wizardry" },
   value: {
       ts: ISODate('2010-10-10T15:01:00Z'),
       total: 254,
       count: 10,
       mean: 25.4 }
}

{
   _id: { u: "rick", d: ISODate("2010-10-10T14:00:00Z"), gender: "male" },
   value: {
       ts: ISODate('2010-10-10T15:01:00Z'),
       total: 254,
       count: 10,
       mean: 25.4 }
}
```

(The values are the same, but the `_id` keys are slightly different.)

This is also well and good.

**Question:**

Now I'd like to aggregate over my hierarchical collections (views), which contain documents having several different compound `_id` fields, but only over documents with `$match`ing `_id` fields. For example, I'd like to aggregate over just the documents possessing the `{u: String, d: Date, hobby: String}` type `_id` or just the documents with an `_id` of type `{u: String, d: Date}`.

I'm aware that I can use the `$exists` operator to restrict which `_id` fields should and shouldn't be permitted, but I don't want to have to create a separate aggregation for each `_id` (potentially many).

Is there a simple way of programmatically restricting `$match`ing documents to those containing (or not containing) particular fields in an aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to address this issues is by storing your data differently. Your "_id" sort of has arbitrary values as key and that is something you should avoid. I would probably store the documents as:

```
{
    _id: { u: "rick", d: ISODate("2010-10-10T14:00:00Z"), type: hobby, value: "wizardry" }
}
{
    _id: { u: "rick", d: ISODate("2010-10-10T14:00:00Z"), type: gender, value: "male" },
}
```

And then your match because simple even without having to create a different match for each type.

Comment: Fair enough, but what if I _have_ to match based solely on `_id` fields?

Comment: In my case, the `_id` fields aren't as simple as I've made them out to be here (e.g., differing by a single field). My question is how to `$match` (potentially using the `$exists` operator) based on the fields present (and not present) in the `_id` field without having to enumerate all possible field combinations. So, provided an `_id` "template" I'd like to aggregate _just_ over the documents having an `_id` field matching the template.

Comment: Why are you sticking all of this stuff in _id anyway?

Comment: It's a result of the map-reduce process.

Comment: I think you should paint the whole picture of what you're trying to do as I'm only seeing a small part - which is not a great base to provide support!

Comment: Could you just give input and desired output(corresponding to given input). So it'd be possible to import those documents and to test.